# Catch items from list which contain specifc string c#

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox, items

lets assume I got a listbox which keeps updating and contains for example:

```
Apple Juice -- 18 EURO
Orange Juice -- 14 EURO
Juice Berry -- 12 EURO
Juice Dates-- 56 EURO
```

And I have a textbox, where I would write the term:

```
Apple
Dates
```

And my desired output would be:

```
Apple Juice -- 18 EURO
Juice Dates -- 56 EURO
```

To clear the confusion, I am trying to build a filter where I have lots of juice types and by typing a favorable juice type it would search for the juice types from the big list and filter them and display them into a standalone favorable list

What I have tryed so far :

```
MyClass result = list.Find(x => x.Id == "Apple");
```

Comment: Where does this `id` come from? Do you have a model? A class of `Juice` maybe? How do you populate the `ListBox`? through the `.DataSource` ?, `.Items.Add(...)`? You should clarify all of that.

Answer (score 2):

The text box in winforms has a [Lines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_TextBoxBase_Lines) property returning a string array. Using it, you could filter with

```
string[] terms = myTextBox.Lines;
var result = list.Find(x => terms.Contains(x.Id));
```

or

```
var result = list.Find(x => Array.FindIndex(terms, t => t == x.Id) != -1);
```

`Find` returns only the first item found. You can use `FindAll` to return a list with all matches.

Comment: @oliverjacot-descombes .id could not be find  :(

Comment: `Id` (with a capital "I" is supposed to be a property of the `MyClass` class. According to your code example, I assumed that you have a `List<MyClass> list`. How is `list` declared? Did you name your `ListBox` like this? If yes, what and how did you add to your `ListBox`? Did you add or bind objects of some kind, did you add strings? We do not have enough information to answer your question. See also @dr.null's comment. We need to see your real code.